# Copy configurable data to children products

Tags: magento

Is there an easy way to set up a system which will copy data from my parent configurable product and apply to it’s simple children products? I would like to copy things like description, product attributes, etc.

Wondering if there is anything built in, or I would have to write a custom script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Louis, as you don't want to use  'Quick simple product creation', why don't you try to import children products from csv file once you have created parents?

Answer (score 0):

That is built in. Create the configurable product first, save it at least once, then on it's Associated Products tab use the "Quick simple product creation" form.

Comment: Unfortunately this will not work for me. I am using the Lightspeed POS system which uploads products into Magento - the product creation step is done as part of this upload. Need to be able to copy the data after they have been created. I began trying to write PHP to do it, but not that familiar with Magento markup.